# debug waitpid taking very long in python runserver

Tags: python, linux, django, profiling

I'm trying to debug why `python manage.py runserver` takes almost two minutes to run. I've been digging around and found cProfile.

`python -m cProfile -o file.prof manage.py runserver` gave me:

```
Wed Mar  2 12:35:24 2016    file.prof

         5705092 function calls (3261657 primitive calls) in 1491.228 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 11227 to 5 due to restriction <5>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        6 1392.536  232.089 1392.536  232.089 {built-in method waitpid}
2860672/492602   45.990    0.000   51.664    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py:325(_iterencode_dict)
   492602    7.650    0.000   59.315    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py:404(_iterencode)
517899/517898    4.323    0.000    4.766    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
       32    3.766    0.118   63.099    1.972 /usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py:175(encode)
```

The formatting is tough here but `waitpid` took the majority of the time (although I'm skeptical it that might be a result of running the profiler). Also `/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py:325(_iterencode_dict)` took almost 46 seconds. How can I dig deeper into this? Where should I turn next? Does this output say anything obvious?

Comment: Any news on this? I am having the same result...

Comment: @AlexGidan nope. it's been a while but if my memory serves me correctly squashing migrations helped us out

Comment: I think in my case it's due to the fact I try to profile the application with celery eager mode = true, so the celery part (the slowest one) is just not profiled and the pid.wait() is profiled instead.